# float div on page below an accordian

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

From the image below you can see that I have a "Quick Tips" div. For examples sake lets say that the outermost div is called: id = "TipsDiv" You can see that it is below the accordion. I want it to stay below the accordion. However when the user scrolls down the div should never go above (0,0). And when the user scrolls back up it should be like it is in the picture.

[image]

If i didn't make my self clear please let me know and i'll try to explain better.

Thanks!

Comment: "If i didn't make my self clear please let me know and i'll try to explain better." - Yeah you'll have to be more specific, scrolls down should never go above 0.0?

Comment: the top left of the screen. pixel 0,0. or 1,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this example I created for another question, with some modification to handle the accordion.  Basically you will need to replace the 250 with the calculated height of the accordion.

http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

Comment: I like it, not sure how I'm going to get the accordion height, there is no convenient get height method. Maybe I could get the height style of the containing div.

Comment: yeah, wrap it in a div and get the hight of that.  If you have any trouble let me know.  If I get some time over the weekend I could probably fiddle around with my fiddle.

Comment: `$("#theFixed").css("top", Math.max(0, $("#sideNav").height() + 25 - $(this).scrollTop()));` The +25 being for the header going across the top of the page that is not part of the side nav. I suppose a better solution would be to get the y cord of the bottom of the side nav, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: small bug here that I found. If you change tabs in the accordion, and don't scroll, the "theFixed" div is no longer right below the accordion. I supposed I can update the position whenever the accordion changes height too...

Comment: Yeah, it will need to adjust any time the accordion changes.  I had thought of that but apparently forgot to come back and update.

Comment: haha, thats ok, I actually ended up making the whole according and this div below it fixed. Makes more sense since the accordion is like a menu.